# Displaying text in left most position in Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

'My Topic' text is displayed in centre at the top. And below that there is a list.
I want to display a '<Back' text at the left most position on the same line as 'My Topic'. How can i achieve this?

Here is the relevant layout XML:

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="My Topic"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/topic"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp" 
                android:divider="#A2B0B0"
                android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"               
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice" >
            </ListView>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your layout with this

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp" >

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relTopic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="My Topic"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/relTopic"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:divider="#A2B0B0"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can take both textview in single layout and then give its reference to listview  `android:layout_below="@id/relTopic"`

Answer (score 0):

Add Relative layout above listview and put back button align to left and my topics text layout_widht="match parent" with gravity center

Here is layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="< Back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="My Topic"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#A2B0B0"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/topbar">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="< Back"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="My Topic"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/topbar"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:divider="#A2B0B0"
            android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" >
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should be the way to go.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="My Topic"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="< Back"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/topic"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#A2B0B0"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this code above your "My Topic":

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="< Back"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

...and set other attributes as you need.